# translate keycode number to actual letter (js)

Tags: javascript, keycode

I have a little problem I cant solve. I made some sort of game to press keys and I use a number generator to generate the numbers of the keys you neet to press. Ofcourse you need to be able to see the letter you need to press, and not just the number js sees.

```
<script>
var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 97);
var p = -10;
var x;
key = 13;
var letter;

function lespres(event) {                                                           //action when key pressed
clock ();
document.getElementById('key2b').innerHTML = "PRESS KEY: " + key;
x = event.which;
document.getElementById('keypressed').innerHTML = "KEY PRESSED: " + x;

if(x == key)    {                                                                   //correct key action
    p = +p + 10;
    document.getElementById('punten').innerHTML = "POINTS: " + p ;
    key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 97);
    document.getElementById('key2b').innerHTML = "PRESS KEY: " + key;
}
else            {                                                                   //incorrect key action
    p = +p - 5;
    document.getElementById('punten').innerHTML = "POINTS: " + p ;
}
}
</script>
```

I made a function to translate key number to letter, but I dont know how to implement it in my code.

```
function lettergen()    {
                        if      (key == 97)     {
                        letter = a;
                        }
                        else if (key == 98)     {
                        letter = b;
                        }
                        else if (key == 99)     {
                        letter = c;
                        }
                    } //and all the way to z
```

If I put this function in the function lespres and change "key" to "letter" in

```
document.getElementById('key2b').innerHTML = "PRESS KEY: " + key;
```

It says "undefined".
Can somebody help me?? help would me much appreciated :D

Comment: Simpler to use [`String#fromCharcode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: What you are looking for is readily available with the `key` property of every [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) object.

Comment: thanks guys thanks to you its working now

Answer (score 0):

`lettergen` function does not return anything (returns `undefined`)

```
function lettergen() {
  // !! avoiding side-effects. variable 'letter' can be defined in higher scope
  var letter = 'unknown';

  if (key == 97) {
    letter = a;
  } else if (key == 98) {
    letter = b;
  } else if (key == 99) {
    letter = c;
  }

  //and all the way to z

  // !!!
  return letter;
}
```

p.s. Maybe it would be simplier if you rewrite your function. Try to use object instead of if-else statements.

```
var KEY_TO_LETTER = {
  97: 'a',
  98: 'b',
}

function lettergen(key) {
  return KEY_TO_LETTER[key]
}
```